# Why zmq ( inproc:// )-connection's order matters, unlike for ( tcp:// )?

Tags: zeromq

When launching a zmq server and client, in any random order, communicating over the **`tcp://`** transport-class, they are smart enough to connect/reconnect regardless of the order.

**However, when trying to run the same over the `inproc://` transport-class, I see that it works only if the client starts after the server. How can we avoid this?**

---

### MCVE-code :

Here are some kotlin MCVE-code examples, to reproduce the claim (this is a modified version of the well known weather example)

**`server.kt`** - run this to run the server standalone

```
package sandbox.zmq

import org.zeromq.ZMQ
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Context
import sandbox.util.Util.sout
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   server(
      context = ZMQ.context(1),
//      publishTo = "tcp://localhost:5556"
      publishTo = "tcp://localhost:5557"
   )
}

fun server(context: Context, publishTo: String) {
   val publisher = context.socket(ZMQ.PUB)
   publisher.bind(publishTo)

   //  Initialize random number generator
   val srandom = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
   while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {
      //  Get values that will fool the boss
      val zipcode: Int
      val temperature: Int
      val relhumidity: Int
      zipcode = 10000 + srandom.nextInt(10)
      temperature = srandom.nextInt(215) - 80 + 1
      relhumidity = srandom.nextInt(50) + 10 + 1

      //  Send message to all subscribers
      val update = String.format("%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity)
      println("server >> $update")
      publisher.send(update, 0)
      Thread.sleep(500)
   }

   publisher.close()
   context.term()
}
```

---

**`client.kt`** - run this for the client standalone

```
package sandbox.zmq

import org.zeromq.ZMQ
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Context
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   client(
      context = ZMQ.context(1),
      readFrom = "tcp://localhost:5557"
   )
}

fun client(context: Context, readFrom: String) {
   //  Socket to talk to server
   println("Collecting updates from weather server")
   val subscriber = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB)
   //        subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:");
   subscriber.connect(readFrom)

   //  Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
   subscriber.subscribe("".toByteArray())

   //  Process 100 updates
   var update_nbr: Int
   var total_temp: Long = 0
   update_nbr = 0
   while (update_nbr < 10000) {
      //  Use trim to remove the tailing '0' character
      val string = subscriber.recvStr(0).trim { it <= ' ' }
      println("client << $string")
      val sscanf = StringTokenizer(string, " ")
      val zipcode = Integer.valueOf(sscanf.nextToken())
      val temperature = Integer.valueOf(sscanf.nextToken())
      val relhumidity = Integer.valueOf(sscanf.nextToken())

      total_temp += temperature.toLong()
      update_nbr++

   }
   subscriber.close()
}
```

---

**`inproc.kt`** - run this and modify which sample is called for the **`inproc://`** scenarios

```
package sandbox.zmq

import org.zeromq.ZMQ
import kotlin.concurrent.thread


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
//   clientFirst()
   clientLast()
}

fun println(string: String) {
   System.out.println("${Thread.currentThread().name} : $string")
}

fun clientFirst() {

   val context = ZMQ.context(1)

   val client = thread {
      client(
         context = context,
         readFrom = "inproc://backend"
      )
   }

   // use this to maintain order
   Thread.sleep(10)

   val server = thread {
      server(
         context = context,
         publishTo = "inproc://backend"
      )
   }

   readLine()
   client.interrupt()
   server.interrupt()
}

fun clientLast() {

   val context = ZMQ.context(1)

   val server = thread {
      server(
         context = context,
         publishTo = "inproc://backend"
      )
   }

   // use this to maintain order
   Thread.sleep(10)

   val client = thread {
      client(
         context = context,
         readFrom = "inproc://backend"
      )
   }

   readLine()
   client.interrupt()
   server.interrupt()
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, [A Look at Nanomsg and Scalability Protocols (Why ZeroMQ Shouldn’t Be Your First Choice)](https://bravenewgeek.com/a-look-at-nanomsg-and-scalability-protocols/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why zmq `inproc://` connection order matters, unlike for `tcp://`?*

Well, this is a by-design behaviour

Given the native ZeroMQ API warns about this by-design behaviour ( since ever ), the issue is not a problem, but an intended property.

Plus one additional property has to be also met:

> *The name* <sup>[ meant `an_endpoint_name` in `.connect("inproc://<_an_endpoint_name_>")`]</sup>
>  ***must*** have been previously created by assigning it to at least one socket
> within the **same** ØMQ context as the socket being connected.

Newer versions of the native ZeroMQ API ( post 4.0 ), **if indeed deployed under one's respective language binding / wrapper,** may allow to release the former of these requirements:

> Since version 4.0 the order of `zmq_bind()` and `zmq_connect()` does not matter just like for the tcp transport type.

---

> *How can we avoid this?*

Well, a much harder part ...

if not already got an easy way above the ZeroMQ native API v4.2+, one may roll up one's sleeves and either re-factor the pre-4.x language wrapper / binding, so as to make the engine get there, or, may be, test if Martin SUSTRIK's second lovely child, the **`nanomsg`** could fit the scene for achieving this.